# Squeezing Non-Zero Elements to Right

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization

I have a tuple in Python, with some non-zero elements.

```
a=(2,2,4,2,0,0,8,8,8,8,8)
```

I'd like a quick way to return the tuple as a list with the zeros to the left, but with the original elements in order. So far, I've attempted the following options:

```
def squeeze(v):
    v_filt=[x for x in v if x != 0]
    return [0]*(len(v)-len(v_filt))+v_filt

def squeeze2(v):
    return sorted(v, key=numpy.sign)
```

The first option is slightly faster, but it still takes 0.866 seconds to carry out 200000 squeezes of tuples of length 4 (on cProfile). My test ran for tuples where each element was as likely to be zero as not.

Is there any way I can make this code run faster? Ideally, I'd like to improve it by at least one to two orders of magnitude.

Comment: Any chances that the tuples might also contain negative values?

Answer (score 2):

If you already use numpy, you can take numpy to do the masking:

```
def squeeze(v):
    c = v[v!=0]
    return numpy.hstack([numpy.zeros(len(v)-len(c)),c])
```

edit: due to Aशwini चhaudhary

Comment: Your code isn't working yet for me - when I run `a[a!=0]`, I get 2. Is there something I'm not doing correctly here? `a` is as above.

Comment: you have to provide a numpy.array instead of a tuple.

Comment: @Daniel You should use `numpy.zeros(len(v)-len(c))` if you are going to do it with numpy, and your will become twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
def squeeze(v):
    result = [None] * len(v)
    i = 0
    j = len(v)-1
    for x in range(len(v)):
        if v[len(v)-x-1] == 0:
            result[i] = 0
            i += 1
        else:
            result[j] = v[len(v)-x-1]
            j -= 1
    return result

import time
import random
a = [random.randint(0,10) for r in xrange(200000)]
start_time = time.time()
squeeze(a)
print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"
```

This takes 0.340382099152 seconds

Comment: Unfortunately this is around 4 times slower than OP's first solution. (Tested with 11000000
 items)

Comment: Thank you. Though wouldn't the time taken depend on the machine. This would have the same big O notation.